# Как получить из Class<Object> сам Object

Tags: kotlin

Вызываю БД функцией в нескольких местах

1. callFunction(call, String::class.java, source)
2. callFunction(call, MyLogicClass::class.java, source)
3. callFunction(call, Long::class.java, source)

сама функция вида

```
private fun <T : Class<*>> callFunction(call: SimpleJdbcCall, targetClass: T, mapParams: MapSqlParameterSource): T {
        try {
            return call.executeFunction(targetClass::class.java, mapParams) as T
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            log.error(e.message)
            throw doWithException(e)
        }
    }
```

все вызовы показывают ошибку

```
Type inference failed. Expected type mismatch: 
required:
String
found:
Class<String>
```

или

Type inference failed. Expected type mismatch:
required:
MyLogicClass
found:
Class

как верно написать функцию чтобы возвращался нужный targetClass: T?

Answer (score 0):

я переписал функцию вот так. стало работать

```
private inline fun <reified T : Any>(call: SimpleJdbcCall, targetClass: Class<T>, mapParams: MapSqlParameterSource): T {
        try {
            return call.executeFunction(targetClass::class.java, mapParams) as T
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            log.error(e.message)
            throw doWithException(e)
        }
    }
```

Comment: зачем вам одновременно ключевое слово reified и параметр targetClass?